# What is the "theoretical" side of love in "Elizabeth Finch" by Julian Barnes?

Tags: meaning, elizabeth-finch, julian-barnes

I'm reading *Elizabeth Finch* by Julian Barnes. In this paragraph I have some difficulties:

1. What is "theoretical" side of love? Is it related to being "conscious" in loving someone?
2. In "**It** is far rooted ..." what does it mean by "**it**"? the"theoretical" side of love" itself? or "rejection" of recognising "theoretical" side of love"?
3. What is meant by "this" (it is bolded in the text)?

> “Love is always a mixture of the visceral and the **theoretical**. Of course, we do not recognise the theoretical as much – **it** is far too rooted in history and kinship. But **this** is why love is essentially artificial. I use that word in the best sense, of course. And what we call romantic love is the most artificial of all. And therefore the highest form, and also the most destructive.”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is "theoretical" side of love? Is it related to being "conscious" in loving someone?

The Cambridge dictionary defines "theoretical" as

> based on the ideas that relate to a subject, not the practical uses of that subject

And we can intuit what the author means from the context of the quote. He states that it is different from the "visceral", that is, the raw passion of love, and further that it is rooted in history and kinship. What he's talking about here, then, are the social constructs that we place around love: the expectations of certain kinds of behaviour that we expect from people in a loving relationship, both toward each other and the way external observers expect them to act.

So to answer the second part of your question, broadly, yes: these are behaviours people consciously or semi-consciously make in order to fit in with societal expectations of being in love, rather than the less controlled emotions attendant on being in love.

> In "It is far rooted ..." what does it mean by "it"? the "theoretical" side of love" itself? or "rejection" of recognising "theoretical" side of love"?

Correct: "it" here is the theoretical side of love.

> What is meant by "this" (it is bolded in the text)?

"This" refers to the statement previously given: that there is a theoretical side of love and that it is rooted in history and kinship.